# How can I prevent hostile mobs from spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a lot of difficulty dealing with hostile mobs. How can I prevent hostile mobs from spawning?

Comment: Why no love Creeper? Why no make Creeper happy? Why no make poor Creeper smile? http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/079/d/d/minecraft_creeper_wallpaper_3_by_full777metal-d3c4ajw.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the difficulty to Peaceful.

Comment: You are right he says but wolf's get hostile on peaceful only on peaceful can someone else tell me how to get wolf's only tamed forever even i hit them tell me an option

Comment: @Wolf Is english a second language for you? I cant understand what your asking in this comment.

Comment: oh i am speaking english

Comment: @Wolf You want the wolves to remain friendly even if you hit them in the game?  Are you hitting them on purpose, or do are you having difficulty with accuracy?  I dislike dealing with mobs, too, so I play on peaceful, but even then, you can't get rid of the danger.  Even without any critters, there's still the risks of falling, burning and drowning to contend with.

Comment: This probably should make some mention of lighting.

Answer (score 2):

I heard lighting torches in caves scares the monsters away.

Comment: not working they will still be there

Comment: illumination prevents mobs spawning there, but it doesn't stop them from walking there from darker places

Answer (score 0):

Set to Peaceful. Small slimes and the Aether's Zephyrs will remain, though.